# How to pass listview image to another class if ItemOnclicks?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my listview class i want to pass the image of clicked item to another class can any one please help how can i do this? I use i.putextra here image is passing... But I am unable to get the image from the intent. I am getting null value if getting this image at another class

```
public class Recipe extends Helper {

    RecipeItems recipeitems;
    ListView list;
    Bitmap bmp;
    String snam;
    String[] recipes = { "Pizza Salads", "Veg Pizza", "Paneer Pizza",
            "Feast Pizza", "Cheese Pizza" };
    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.cheese, R.drawable.paneer,
            R.drawable.vegpizza, R.drawable.cheese, R.drawable.paneer };
    Integer[] prices = { 400, 300, 400, 200, 500 };
    String[] description = {
            "Mouth watering pizza salads is waiting for your curush...",
            "Mouth watering veg pizza is waiting for your curush...",
            "Mouth watering paneer pizza is waiting for your curush...",
            "Mouth watering Feast pizza is waiting for your curush...",
            "Mouth watering cheese pizza is waiting for your curush..." };
    String[] status = { "Out of Stock", "Add to Cart", "Out of Stock",
            "Add to Cart", "Out of Stock" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        RecipeItems adapter = new RecipeItems(Recipe.this, recipes, imageId,
                prices, description, status);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipeslist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("null")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for (int i =-1; i < position; i++) {
                    snam = recipes[position];
                    Log.e("", "recipe name---" + snam);

                }



                // intent.putExtra("position", item);
                /*intent.putExtra("recipe", recipe);

                intent.putExtra("snam", snam);
                intent.putExtra("imageId",imageId);*/

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        DetailedRecipe.class);


                intent.putExtra("id", position);
                intent.putExtra("snam", snam);
                intent.putExtra("imageId", imageId);


                Log.e("", "passing image---"+imageId);


                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: put the image from array like `intent.putExtra("imageId", ""+imageId[position]);`

Comment: I can pass like i.putextra("imageId",imageId[position]), and at othere class getting int position = i.getExtras().getInt("imageId"); but emoty value

Comment: you got the correct value at the time of onitemclicklistener but you not get it in Detailedrecipe.class

Comment: @Yugesh I got it by using this code...Intent i = getIntent();
   // Selected image id
   int position = i.getExtras().getInt("imageId");
   
   imageId = i.getIntArrayExtra("imageId");
   imageView.setImageResource(position);

Comment: You got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Recipe extends Helper {

RecipeItems recipeitems;
ListView list;
Bitmap bmp;
String snam;
String[] recipes = { "Pizza Salads", "Veg Pizza", "Paneer Pizza",
        "Feast Pizza", "Cheese Pizza" };
Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.cheese, R.drawable.paneer,
        R.drawable.vegpizza, R.drawable.cheese, R.drawable.paneer };
Integer[] prices = { 400, 300, 400, 200, 500 };
String[] description = {
        "Mouth watering pizza salads is waiting for your curush...",
        "Mouth watering veg pizza is waiting for your curush...",
        "Mouth watering paneer pizza is waiting for your curush...",
        "Mouth watering Feast pizza is waiting for your curush...",
        "Mouth watering cheese pizza is waiting for your curush..." };
String[] status = { "Out of Stock", "Add to Cart", "Out of Stock",
        "Add to Cart", "Out of Stock" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    RecipeItems adapter = new RecipeItems(Recipe.this, recipes, imageId,
            prices, description, status);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipeslist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DetailedRecipe.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", position);
            intent.putExtra("snam", snam);
            intent.putExtra("imageId", imageId[position]);
            startActivity(intent);


            for (int i =-1; i < position; i++) {
                snam = recipes[position];
                Log.e("", "recipe name---" + snam);

            }


        }
    });}}
```

You want to move creating an Intent to the listener and also passing a single Image (if that's what you want). The code is above.